# Error "smbclient '//infong-es180/POS' -c 'print -' -N" failed with exit code 127: sh: 1: smbclient: not found

Tags: php, print

Acudo a vosotros como ultimo recurso ya que estoy intentando enviar un ticket para su impresión desde mi hosting 1and1 a una impresora térmica marca "aqprx" la cual esta conectada a mi PC.

Es todo muy raro a que cuando hago las pruebas en mi `localhost` imprime el ticket a la primera, sin retraso ni demora pero cuando lo subo al servidor me da este error:

> ("smbclient '//infong-es180/POS' -c 'print -' -N" failed with exit code 127: sh: 1: smbclient: not found).

Alguna posible idea o solución ???. a continuación os dejo el código escrito en `PHP`.

```
     <?php
    require __DIR__ . '/ticket/autoload.php';
    use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
    use Mike42\Escpos\EscposImage;
    use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;

    try {
 // Enter the share name for your printer here, as a smb:// url format

$nombre_impresora = ("POS"); 
$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector($nombre_impresora);
$printer = new Printer($connector);


  /* Print a "Hello world" receipt" */
    $printer = new Printer($connector);
    $printer -> text("Hello World!\n");
    $printer -> cut();

    /* Close printer */
    $printer -> close();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error=>No se pudo imprimir en esta impresora: " . $e -> getMessage() . "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué distribución de linux usas? Necesitas encontrar qué paquete contiene esa utilidad y cómo instalarla.

Comment: @OscarGarcia No uso distribucion Linux - tengo mi hosting en un servidor con Windows

Comment: Es extraño porque por norma general Windows no usa la shell `sh` (como puede apreciarse en `sh: 1: smbclient: not found`) ni requiere de `smbclient` (cliente de cifs). ¿Podrías usar [`phpinfo()`](https://php.net/es/phpinfo) en un PHP de prueba para comprobar el sistema operativo? En la primera línea aparecerá (junto a **System**) los detalles del sistema operativo sobre el que se ejecuta el servidor.

Comment: @OscarGarcia ok dame un momento y lo compruebo

Comment: @OscarGarcia Pues el sistema que utiliza 1and1 el el servidor es Linux (System Linux info 3.0 #1337 SMP Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 CEST 2000 all GNU/Linux) , alguna idea DE COMO LOPUEDO SOLUCIONAR

Comment: Debes solicitar al servicio de soporte de ese proveedor que instale (o si hay posibilidad) `smbclient` en él. En caso contrario deberás cambiar la biblioteca de funciones de impresión a una que no dependa de esa herramienta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No vas a poder imprimir desde la página web que tienes alojada en el servicio de hosting compartido de 1and1 por dos motivos:

### Limitaciones de un alojamiento compartido

No puedes instalar aplicaciones como `smbclient` en un servicio de alojamiento compartido como el que ofrece 1and1 si dicha herramienta no estaba previamente disponible.

Una solución podría ser la contratación de un VPS, en el que podrías instalar todo el software que desees, pero entonces te encontrarás con la segunda limitación.

### Limitaciones en las comunicaciones

No puedes establecer una conexión a un recurso compartido de tu máquina local desde el servidor de 1and1 sin establecer una VPN o mapear puertos desde tu router.

En el primer caso podrías establecer la VPN si fuera un VPS administrado por ti, pero probablemente no sea posible hacerlo desde el alojamiento compartido de 1and1.

En el segundo caso deberías configurar la IP externa para el acceso, pero en tu mensaje de error estás configurando un nombre de equipo local (`//infong-es180/POS`), que no puede resolverse por DNS en el lado de 1and1 ni tienen acceso a la IP interna de tu red sin establecer una VPN.